# Django update or create existing row in database does not work

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I am using Django 3.0.2, database SQLite. I create model weight:

```
class Weight(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    weight = models.FloatField()
```

My goal is to create row for every day. If I will write more time per day, only last_modified and weight will be updated depends on user_id and date.

From command line, I can create new row, but cant update it. When I try this:

```
Weight.objects.update_or_create(user_id=2, weight=123, date=date.today())
Weight.objects.update_or_create(user_id=2, weight=456, date=date.today())
```

It will create two row:

```
1   2020-02-01 16:22:57.275688  123 2   2020-02-01
2   2020-02-01 16:23:02.925780  456 2   2020-02-01
```

I would expect one row in the output:

```
1   2020-02-01 16:22:57.275688  456 2   2020-02-01
```

If I use **update** instead of **update_or_create**, I am able to update it.

Can anybody help me to explain why it does not work? Maybe I am missing something but cant figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify with wath default values you want to update the object.

`Weight.objects.update_or_create(user_id=2, date=date.today(),defaults={'weight':456})`